# Why is this XSLT returns nothing for the XML values?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

After applying the XSLT to the XML,I want to display the item name and description from the XML, I only have the table headings displaying, seems name and description from the XML did not get picked up, anyone knows why? Anything to do with the "tns:" namespace?? Thanks!!

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="./LittleStore.xsl"?>
<tns:store xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/LittleStore/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/LittleStore/ LittleStore.xsd ">

  <tns:item>

    <name>Warm Hat</name>
    <description>This hat is warm and will mike you stand out from the crowd.</description>

  </tns:item>

  <tns:manufacturer>
    <manu_id>4234</manu_id>
    <name>Toy Co.</name>
  </tns:manufacturer>

</tns:store>
```

And here is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/LittleStore/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Store Catalog</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="store/item">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the namespace? Like `tns:store/tns:item` and `tns:name` ? (You already hinted at the namespace in the question..)

Comment: Great! It works now! thank you. I added tns:store/tns:item.  By the way, if I add tns:name or tns:description it actually gives empty cells for the table. Anyways, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The solution: I added tns:store/tns:item.

By the way, if I add tns:name or tns:description it actually gives empty cells for the table.